# How to find percentage from two tables with 2 different headings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, Reports with offender_id and Games with account_id. Each account has multiple games and some have a number of reports against them.

I need to be able to return the percentage of games each account has been reported for.

Games

```
account_id  
1     
1     
1     
2     
2     
2     
3     
3
```

Reports

```
offender_id   
1     
2    
2     
3     
3
```

Required Report Result

```
ID   PercentageReported    
1       33%                         
2       66%                         
3       100%
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Can you show an entity-relationship-diagram please? Click File->Import->Reverse Engineer MySQL Create Script.
Click Browse and select your SQL create script.
Make Sure "Place Imported Objects on a diagram" is checked.
Click Execute Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this right, then perhaps each game played is recorded in `Games` table and each offence in `Reports`?

So, if that's the case, then the query could possibly be written as follows:

```
SELECT temp1.account_id, gamesPlayedCount, 
       IFNULL(gamesOffendedCount, 0) AS gamesOffendedCount, 
       CAST(100*IFNULL(gamesOffendedCount, 0)/gamesPlayedCount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) 
                                                               AS offencePercentage
       FROM
       (
         SELECT g.account_id, COUNT(g.account_id) AS gamesPlayedCount 
                FROM GamesPlayed g
         GROUP BY g.account_id
       ) AS temp1
       LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT r.offender_id, COUNT(r.offender_id) AS gamesOffendedCount 
                FROM Reports r
         GROUP BY r.offender_id
       ) AS temp2
ON temp1.account_id = temp2.offender_id
```

Comment: This is perfect ty! But If I am being honest I dont fully understand it. Why is there a temp1 and temp2? and why is there a small g and small r?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Well... `COUNT` can only be computed on a collective group. When we make a `JOIN`, we would get all the rows at once and won't be able to distinguish how many rows originated from which table. So, we create two branches within the query - one which finds out the number of records per id in `Games` table and the other which does the same in `Reports` table. If I may propose, please do try to run those queries within the brackets independently to get a better idea.

Comment: Now, we take the two result sets thus produced (call the first as `temp1` and the second as `temp2`) and simply `JOIN` them over `account_id = offender_id`. `offencePercentage` can thus be calculated. `g` and `r` are simply aliases for `Games` and `Reports` table respectively. We can access any fields using the aliases as `x.field` (rather than `table.field`). This can be particularly useful if there are two or more tables and each have column names that look very similar. Using aliases helps the SQL engine to identify (with a shortcut) the table from which a given field can be sourced.

Comment: Thankyou for explaining. I understand it alot better now :)

Comment: @CH99 Sorry, I've just made an edit in the query. The query with an `INNER JOIN` won't produce any rows for a user who hasn't offended in any games so far. Meaning, there won't be any direct measure to tell for a user that they've maintained a `0.00%` offence record. So, the query is modified a little to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead and therefore the `IFNULL` checks to ensure that `NULL` values are replaced with `0`. Sorry, it didn't occur to me before...!!